# Preventing "pending" payments for Shopsystem

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I don't understand the issue about pending (stautus) payments. Im working on a customer-project for a pizza delivery-service. I understood, that the pending status can stay for about 10 days. But what does this exactly mean. 
My questions:

1. Does this mean, that the pizza delivery-service gets his money in up to 10 days? And is this guaranteed?
2. Is there a way to prevent "pending" payments.
3. How would you solve this issue especially for a pizza delivery service.

Info: Im using the actual restful PHP Api

Answer (score 0):

Pending status is related to Authorization payment in PayPal. You shall check the code about 'paymentaction=authorization'. It should be set as 'paymentaction=sale'. In Shopsystem, find out the configuration field to set this option into Sale.